# Вычисление контрольный суммы для ICMP

Tags: c#, сетевое-программирование

Есть программа учебная, для отправки своих пакетов. Возникла проблема с вычислением контрольной суммы для ICMP заголовка третьего типа, то есть, отправка об ошибке (порт недоступен).
Пакет формируется из Ethernet-Layer'a 2 версии, IPv4 заголовка, ICMP заголовка и UDP(вместе с IPv4 заголовком для него)
Итак, теперь к вопросу, никак не догоняю какие байты пакета используются для вычисления контрольной суммы ICMP заголовка. Объяснения для меня в RFC(https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc792) было непонятном, поэтому обращаюсь сюда, надеясь на помощь. Все остальные контрольные суммы верны.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код создания пакета: https://pastebin.com/q1F3bWni (без кода псевдозаголовка UDP, да он и не нужен, ведь с ним всё впорядке)
Код вычисления контрольной суммы: https://pastebin.com/72tmxMi7 (входные данные для расчёта контрольной суммы: сам собственно набор данных, второе значение - откуда начинать. Третье же - сколько смещаться с текущего места вперёд)

Comment: Чтобы увеличить шансы ответа, добавьте ссылку на RFC или кусок из него, который вам не понятен, и ваш код/псевдокод. Понимаете, очень немногим людям может потребоваться уметь вычислять icmp checksum, поэтому из головы вам вряд ли кто-то даст алгоритм... А куда-то лезть и искать для вас и вместо вас...

Comment: Мне нужен не код расчёта, он у меня есть. Мне нужно какие данные в пакете идут на счёт контрольной суммы. Так что скорее не по коду вопрос, то, как его сделать я справлюсь сам. Сссылку оставлю на RFC, на всякий

Comment: Так и я не про код, а про алгоритм. "какие байты" - это часть алгоритма..

Comment: кстати - я совершенно случайно увидел, что вы тут что-то написали... Если хотите, чтобы человек получил уведомление в личку, добавляйте "ник с собакой" - типа так: @tum_ Почитайте вообще, как этим ресурсом пользоваться - пригодится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update, посмотрев выложенный код:

Если коротко, контрольные суммы у вас считаются в обратном порядке.
Т.е. получается, что вы ICMP checksum посчитали, а потом те данные, по которым она считалась, взяли и поменяли, вставив туда UDP checksum и т.д.
Надо начинать с самого "внутреннего" пакета (UDP в вашем случае) и идти в обратном порядке.
Если других ошибок нет, то должно заработать.

А эта ошибка от того, что не понимаете "физического смысла" того, что делаете. Разберитесь с инкапсуляцией сетевых пакетов (типа такого "http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_IPDatagramEncapsulation.htm", вам должны были всё это на лекциях давать).

Оригинальный ответ:
RFC792 говорит (для Destination Unreachable Message, приведенного в вопросе):
Checksum:
      The checksum is the 16-bit ones's complement of the one's
      complement sum of the ICMP message starting with the ICMP Type.
      For computing the checksum , the checksum field should be zero.
      This checksum may be replaced in the future.

То есть, глядя на ваш пример, начиная с Type: 3 и до конца Data. При этом 2 байта отведенные под checksum во время вычисления должны быть заполнены нулями. Потом на их место положить вычисленный результат.
Для других типов могут быть нюансы с padding (см. Echo), так что надо быть внимательным.

Comment: До конца Data, то есть, включая IPv4 Header под ним и UDP? Они стоят между ICMP и концом Data. Но всё равно результат неверный. К тому же в UDP вычисляется уже контрольная сумма для Data.

Comment: Про неверный результат ничего нельзя сказать, не видя, как вы его получаете, не так ли?  То что в UDP вычисляется - вычислялось при формировании UDP пакета, если я правильно понимаю (опять же вы ничего не рассказали о том, что происходит и зачем всё это нужно). Для ICMP все эти хедеры - это просто данные, которые надо завернуть в ICMP пакет и отправить.

Comment: Вот весь код, где я создаю этот пакет: https://pastebin.com/q5GFDh9E
Вот так я получаю результат, просто беру кусок данных и засовываю их в метод, откуда он вычисляет контрольную сумму. Ещё есть псевдозаголовок, но думаю без него понятно, что к чему.

Comment: входные данные для расчёта контрольной суммы: сам собственно набор данных, второе значение - откуда начинать. Третье же - сколько смещаться с текущего места вперёд. То есть, ComputeChecksum(byte[] Packet, int StartIndex, int lenght)

Comment: шапку обновил, надеюсь на помощь (тема для меня оказалось какой-то неподъёмной).

Comment: Тогда следующий вопрос, как должен выглядеть конечный результат кода для вычисления контрольной суммы. Код то не мой, а побитовые операции со смещением, сложением и прочим, тёмный лес. Так что простите на нубство.

Comment: Предыдущий комментарий удалил. Нормально выглядит ComputeChecksum, должен правильно считать. Ошибка у вас в коде. Сейчас ещё раз посмотрю и отредактирую свой ответ.

Comment: А конкретнее можно чуть, где я  в коде накосячил? Вроде всё нормально вычисляю, начиная с Type заканчивая Data.

Comment: Update в ответе прочитали?

Comment: Цитирую: "То есть, глядя на ваш пример, начиная с Type: 3 и до конца Data. При этом 2 байта отведенные под checksum во время вычисления должны быть заполнены нулями. Потом на их место положить вычисленный результат." Всё по инструкции

Comment: Абзац про "в обратном порядке" не понятен или игнорируете? Ответ в нём.

Comment: понял, обычно когда пост обновляют, в конце добавляют инфу. На начало не обратил внимание